# Set up SFTP to not require private key

Tags: centos, openssh, sftp, key-authentication

So I have this server I log on with my sudoer account via SSH using a key. I have also created another, restricted, account so that I can give another user access to SFTP files into a specific folder.

Now, when I try to connect using sftp, it´s still spitting invalid key back at me.

I would like that specific user to be able to SFTP using only username and password. Any help here is appreciated, thanks!

Daniel

Comment: Sounds like you need to modify the Authentication Methods section of your `/etc/sshd_config`.   `man sshd_config` for the gory details.

Comment: Without knowing how is your sshd configured, all the answers are only blind shots to the dark.

Comment: He wants to allow a password logon. Simple enough for a new account.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
Define the following exception in sshd by adding this block for each user name:

```
Match User username
 ChrootDirectory %h
 ForceCommand internal-sftp
 PasswordAuthentication yes
```

If you have multiple accounts, it's easier to have a group catch:

```
Match Group sftp
  ChrootDirectory %h
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  PasswordAuthentication yes
```

For the sake of clarity, you meant: No public key requirement. A private key stay's on the client's workstation/server.

After this, reload sshd and you're good to go. 
Read more about it at https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest and simplest solution is to create a second `sshd` daemon which has a different config file and so different attributes.  This one can specify the ONE user that is allowed to use it and the account can be set with whatever credentials are appropriate.

I for example have a second server, invoked with:

```
/usr/sbin/sshd -f /etc/ssh/sshd_config1
```

The config1 file specifies a different port,

```
Port 2134
AllowUsers xxxxy yyyyx
AuthenticationMethods password
PubkeyAuthentication no
```